# Problem of reading OWL/XML

Tags: java, xml, owl, jena

I have a problem reading OWL/XML files from Java using Jena.

I have no problem reading RDF/XML files, but whenever I create a OWL/XML file from Protege and try to read it, Java gives this error below :
WARN [main] (RDFDefaultErrorHandler.java:36)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.arp.impl.XMLHandler.endElement(XMLHandler.java:143)

The code that I use to retrieve RDF/XML is below :

```
OntModel ontModel = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel();
InputStream in = FileManager.get().open(inputFileName);
    if (in == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException( "File: " + inputFileName + " not found");
    }
    ontModel.read(in, "");
```

This code works with RDF/XML perfectly. However, I cannot read an OWL/XML. I looked at Internet and I couldn't find anything.
I would really appreciate, if someone shows me a way.
Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jena does not support OWL/XML. It ships with readers for RDF/XML, Turtle (a.k.a. N3) and N-Triples. See for example [here](http://jena.sourceforge.net/javadoc/com/hp/hpl/jena/rdf/model/Model.html#read(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) for the list of supported formats.

Comment: What should I use to read OWL/XML files ? Is there a library like Jena to read this kind of files ? Or, is it meaningful to convert OWL/XML to RDF/XML ?

Comment: Just use RDF/XML. I'm pretty sure that it can express everything that OWL/XML can express.

Answer (score 3):

For OWL/XML use the [OWL-API](http://owlapi.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: Yes, I have used OWL-API and it works perfectly. Thanks for your precious advices, Kaarel and cygi.

Answer (score 0):

You can find a good answer here.

- [http://answers.semanticweb.com/questions/15004/using-jena-to-access-an-owlxml-file-made-from-protege](https://web.archive.org/web/20160816154309/http://answers.semanticweb.com:80/questions/15004/using-jena-to-access-an-owlxml-file-made-from-protege)

I tested the code that is provided in the 4th answer and it works for me 100%. I copied the answer here for you.

```
String inputFileName = "D:\Ontologia\OntoSME_V7.owl";

OntModel onto = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel(OntModelSpec.OWL_DL_MEM, null);

try {
    InputStream in = FileManager.get().open(inputFileName);
    onto.read(in, "RDF/XML");
} catch (JenaException je) {
    System.out.println("ERROR" + je.getMessage());
    je.printStackTrace();
    System.exit(0);
}
```

you can use protege to save the file in RDF/XML format and read the file with above technique.

Answer (score 0):

[ONT-API](https://github.com/owlcs/ont-api) can read OWL/XML documents (and any other OWL formats) as a Jena's RDF Graph