# CRUD Operation in OWL

Tags: java, php, owl, protege

I have created an ontology. Now I want to create an application but how can I perform CRUD operations in owl file. I came across different apis like Dotnetrdf, jena etc all support RDF/RDFS but there is not support for owl file

http://www.semanticoverflow.com/questions/2704/using-jena-to-query-owl-files

[Problem of reading OWL/XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3029034/problem-of-reading-owl-xml)

Also, most of apis are available in Java and I dont know how to write simple **hello world** program in java. I am confused with servlet, jsp and .java and lots of configuration is required. So I prefer php.

So is there any api or any alternative way to query owl file in php ?

Regards,
anas anjaria

Answer (score 1):

The only libraries I know that support SW standards in PHP are rdfapi [1] and redland php binding [2], but the level is RDF (i.e. the building block of RDFS and OWL) you will need to add CRUD operations at the triple level (i.e. simple axioms like  foaf:knows )

[1] http://www4.wiwiss.fu-berlin.de/bizer/rdfapi/

[2] http://librdf.org/docs/php.html

Comment: Thanx for your response , but rdfapi support rdf not owl. Owl is an extension of rdf. We can add intellligence in owl file. There are axiom which have support in owl file but not rdf.

Answer (score 0):

So, it looks like you're talking about the [Web Ontology Language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Ontology_Language), an XML/RDF dialect.

A few moments in Google shows pretty much zero interest in this in the world of PHP.

But, being XML, you can [use one of the PHP XML extensions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/refs.xml.php) so read and work with the XML directly without a problem.  How well this will actually work for you, I can't say.  OWL looks freakishly complex, and working with it at the DOM node level will very likely stretch your sanity *far worse* than working with mature, established libraries in Java.

Answer (score 0):

i made  my final project at the  university  by using  Jena. The Research Group where  i work develop  ontology generator tool which is capable of  all crud operations. They also developed the Eclipse plug-in of this  project.

You  just  create your  OWL Data Model in the editor and right  click the data model create everything, i creates owl files, Crud class and it's  test  codes for you.

Let's check it out

[Download](http://etmen.ege.edu.tr/wiki/index.php/Download)

Name of Plug-in is "SEAGENT Ontology Generator Plugin (Beta)"

I hope  it will be beneficial for you  like me

Comment: Can u plz tell me your email address so that I can contact with you. Its also my final year project